EKS DR Strategy - How to control container activation in warm standby region
I have an EKS cluster with a warm standby in another AWS region for disaster recovery. Some of my containerized applications process data and forward it to other systems - I need to ensure these processors don't run in both regions simultaneously to prevent duplicate processing.
I need the fastest possible failover time and cannot make application-level changes. I considered setting replica count to 0 in the standby region and then patching ConfigMaps during failover to control this behavior. However, I'm not convinced this is the best approach as it:

Slows down the failover process
Requires tracking which applications need to be patched during failover
Adds complexity to the failover procedure

Are there better approaches to handle this requirement?
